# Call matlab static method from within another static method

Tags: matlab, static-methods

is it possible to call a static method from another static method, both method belonging to the same class? Or is there some special syntax that I am not aware of? Currently I am trying to do the following:

```
% Circle.m
classdef Circle
    methods (Static)
        function p = getPi
            p = 3.14;
        end

        function a = getArea( r )
            a = r * Circle.getPi * Circle.getPi;
        end
    end
end
```

And then:

```
>> Circle.getPi  
ans =  
3.1400  

>> Circle.getArea(123)  
Undefined variable "Circle" or class "Circle.getPi".  

Error in utils.Circle.getArea (line 8)  
            a = r * Circle.getPi * Circle.getPi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows that your class is `utils.Circle`, not `Circle`. Your class is placed inside a package `utils.`

Answer (score 5):

See the section [Referencing Package Members Within Packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html#br_lltt) in the documentation page called ["Packages Create Namespaces"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html).  Basically it says that normal methods from instances of a class do not require the package prefix, but with static methods it is required.  Evidently this applies even when calling a static method, from another class method!

> All references to packages, functions, and classes in the package must use the package name prefix, unless you import the package. (See Importing Classes.) For example, call a package function with this syntax:
>
> ```
> z = mypack.pkfcn(x,y);
> ```
>
> Note that definitions do not use the package prefix. For example, the function definition line of the pkfcn.m function would include only the function name:
>
> [snip]
>
> Calling class methods does not require the package name because you have an instance of the class:
>
> ```
> obj.myMethod(arg) or  
> myMethod(obj,arg)
> ```
>
> **A static method requires the full class name**:
>
> ```
> mypack.myClass.stMethod(arg)
> ```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is as good as the one given by @Daniel (minus the very useful links and the lengthy example), however he answered earlier so I accepted his.

Comment: @brtk That's fine.  Glad it is helpful.